# E0308 during String variable assignment

Tags: rust

I am trying to read text files and use [the text-summarize library](https://github.com/nfinger/text-summarize) to generate short summaries. As far as I can tell, it accepts a string, passes it to an open API for a text summary website and returns the summary.

I am trying to write a simple script to read a local file, summarize and return the summary.

```rust
use std::fs;
mod lib;

fn main() {
    println!("In file {}", "poem.txt");
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("poem.txt").expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);
    let summ = lib::summarize_text(contents);
}
```

However, the contents variable I pass to the `summarize_text` function is the wrong kind of string and at this point I have no idea why. I checked the `rustc --explain E0308` which was suggested as a helpful link but didn't understand the discussion.

Comment: Shouldn't message in a error "help: consider borrowing here: `&contents`" the solution?

Comment: Thanks, that does help! It compiles now. I'm a little confused how to know when variables need & prepended, do you have any documentation that would help that?

Comment: There's ownership in the book ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html), particular you might be interested in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) section.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Kitsu, I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! Next time, provide the complete error that might be helpful both for those who answer and those who searching for their issues.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error itself is self-descriptive I believe:

```
26 |     let summ = lib::summarize_text(contents);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^
   |                                    |
   |                                    expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |                                    help: consider borrowing here: `&contents`
```

Library accepts the `&str` slice, but you provided an owned `String` object, so you need to make a conversion, you may write it like this:

```rust
let summ = lib::summarize_text(&contents);

// or more explicit version
let summ = lib::summarize_text(contents.as_str());
```